# Error when running Anaconda navigator

Tags: linux, anaconda, conda

I get this error when running anaconda-navigator on Linux Mint 18.1:

```
QApplication: invalid style override passed, ignoring it.
2018-03-20 19:54:36,039 - ERROR anaconda_api.is_vscode_available:871
''

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/
api/anaconda_api.py", line 368, in _conda_info_processed
    processed_info = self._process_conda_info(info)
  File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/
api/anaconda_api.py", line 479, in _process_conda_info
    processed_info = info.copy()
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'copy'
...
```

I updated using:

```
conda update conda
conda update anaconda-navigator
conda update navigator-updater
```

The versions are:

```
conda 4.5.0
anaconda Command line client (version 1.6.14)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea *how* or *why* this works, but if you delete the `.condarc` file in your user folder, it starts to work fine. At least for me and some users here:
https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/11734#issuecomment-638591004

Putting this here in case anyone else runs into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me, It was only the fact that I modified too much my file .condarc.
I restored back and solved my issue

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30952648)